# Sharepoint Cannot Perform the operation. The file is no longer checked out or has been deleted

Tags: sharepoint

I created a new document from a SharePoint Template.
Entered text in body of document.
Saved file.
Updated Title from Doc Properties Panel.
Saved file – ok
Closed document – "Do you want to check in?"
Clicked Yes – 0.1 version, clicked OK.
Got this error: "Cannot Perform the operation. The file is no longer checked out or has been deleted."

Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I quite often had this issue with the Sharepoint Designer. My problem was solved by clearing the cache of the Sharepoint Designer as shown here:

http://www.raihaniqbal.net/blog/2013/02/sharepoint-designer-the-file-is-no-longer-checked-out-or-has-been-deleted/

Create a batch (*bat) with a editor with following code:

```
cd "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache"
del *.web /S /Q "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache"
cd "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\"
rmdir /S /Q "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache\."
mkdir "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache"
dir "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Web Server Extensions\Cache"
dir "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WebsiteCache"
pauseenter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

There are so many reasons which may cause this issue.

One of them may be is

`Alternative Access Mappings` were set to access the site as

if your site is configured to be use as `http://site.company.com`  and if you are accessing the site as `http://site`,  then this may happen .

start using the full address and hope the problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already cleared the cache and the problem still persists you should check the title of your file and ensure that it does not contain disallowed characters. To do that I followed the instructions in [this article](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/09/we-cant-do-that-for-you-because-the-file-is-no-loger-checked-out-or-has-been-deleted/). It helped me and I hope it helps you.